# What does "suitable for symbolic manipulation" in the documentation mean?

Tags: symbolic, documentation, implementation-details

This question is related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6326110/353410) I posted on Stack Overflow some time ago. There, in a beautiful answer, [acl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16/acl) (with some unhumble editing done by me) showed that the derivative of `IntegerPart` is calculated numerically by a centered difference method of eighth order.

If you read the help for `IntegerPart[]` you'll find:

> Mathematical function, suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation.

At that time I assumed it was just a documentation (or program) bug.

I revisited the problem today because I needed to solve an equation that can be tracked down to something like:

```
Reduce[IntegerPart@x == x, x, Reals]
(*
-> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
*)
```

So again, Mma's failure to "symbolically manipulate" the `IntegerPart[]` function is bothering me. And this time, the derivative calculation is not the issue.

All these functions `{IntegerPart, FractionalPart, Ceiling, Floor, Round, PrimePi}` share the

> Mathematical function, suitable for both symbolic and numerical manipulation.

legend in their help reference.

Look at their derivatives:

```
f = {IntegerPart, FractionalPart, Ceiling, Floor, Round, PrimePi};
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
   Plot[{#[u], D[#[x], x] /. x -> u}, {u, -1, 3}, 
       PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[Hyperlink[#, "paclet:ref/" <> #] &@ToString@#], 16,
                          Blue, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]]] & /@ f, 
  2], 
 Frame -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Moreover, the help file for `NextPrime[]` doesn't state anything about its symbolic manipulation suitability, and the help for `HeavisideTheta[]` says:

> HeavisideTheta can be used in integrals, integral transforms and differential equations.

and its derivative is evaluated as `DiracDelta[]`.

When you plot these functions you get:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

So it seems that from the whole set, only `HeavisideTheta` is treated symbolically.

However, when you try:

```
Reduce[HeavisideTheta@x == 1, x, Reals]
(*
-> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
*)
```

So the "symbolical manipulation" is not there (or so it looks like).

So the question is: **What does it mean for a *Mathematica* function to be "suitable for symbolic manipulation"?**

Comment: It's about time someone asked this. **+1**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've always considered the *"suitable for symbolic manipuation"* line to be a bit of truth wrapped in marketing speak and not meant to mean anything mathematically precise. The documentation center guides and tutorials are good examples of hyperbole in technical documentation (see for instance, the opening lines in [Mathematical Typesetting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html)).

Coming to the "bit of truth" part, I believe WRI's interpretation of "symbolic manipulation" is reflected in [Symbolic Calculations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicCalculations.html)

> With *Mathematica*, you can differentiate an expression symbolically, and get a formula for the result.

So it's a simple interpretation which roughly means formula in, formula out. Whether expressions can be manipulated symbolically or not depends heavily on the internal implementation and as noted in the same document:

> There are however many circumstances where it is mathematically impossible to get an explicit formula as the result of a computation.

Now coming to your `HeavisideTheta` example, here's a function that is *effectively* the same:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {1, x > 0}}, HeavisideTheta[0]]
```

Now let's try some symbolic manipulations on each of them

```
funcs = {f, HeavisideTheta};
Integrate[#[x], {x, -2, 2}] & /@ funcs
(* {2, 2} *)

Table[Limit[#[x], x -> 0, Direction -> i] & /@ funcs, {i, {1, -1}}]
(* {{0, 0}, {1, 1}} *)

FourierTransform[#[x], x, w] & /@ funcs
(* {I/(Sqrt[2 π]] w) + Sqrt[π/2] DiracDelta[w], I/(Sqrt[2 π] w) + Sqrt[π/2] DiracDelta[w]} *)
```

Looks good... but:

```
Integrate[D[#[x], x], {x, -1, 1}] & /@ funcs
(* {0, 1} *)

Simplify[Reduce[#[x] == 1, x, Reals], Assumptions -> HeavisideTheta[0] != 1] & /@ funcs
(* x > 0, Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >> } *)
```

So you can see that the built-in implementation knows how to differentiate `HeavisideTheta` correctly and the trade-off for that added knowledge is additional complexity which makes `Reduce` choke when trying to solve a relatively simple expression.

Comment: So your POV is that the manuals are written in [**Newspeak**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak). Interesting ...