# Managing Exclusions in Plot[ ]

Tags: plotting, symbolic

When I do:

```
l = {5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5};
f = Interpolation@l;
g[t_] = D[f[t], t];
p1 = Plot[{f@x, g@x + 4}, {x, 1, Length@l}, Evaluated -> True,   Exclusions -> True]
```

I expect:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, since `Plot[]` doesn't detect the discontinuities, I get:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I have two ways to overcome this, but none of them is robust enough.

The first one is excluding explicitly those points where the derivative changes a lot in a small interval. The problem here is that **"a lot"** and **"small"** are not defined clearly in my textbook.
Please note that `Exclusions ->` doesn't accept inequalities (well, it does, but only as an AND clause for equalities)

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval];
Plot[{f@x, g@x + 4}, {x, 1, Length@l}, 
      Exclusions -> {UnitStep[Abs[g[x] - g[x + .01]] - .5] == 1},
      Evaluated -> True]
On[InterpolatingFunction::dmval];
```

The second one displays the same problems.

```
Plot[{f@x, g[x] + 4}, {x, 1, 7}, Evaluated -> True] //. 
     Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, b___}] /; Abs[(y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)] > 10 -> 
    {Line[{a, {x1, y1}}], Line[{{x2, y2}, b}]}
```

I tried a few things, including `PlotPoints->` and `MaxRecursion->` to no avail.
For example `RegionFunction[]` gives disappointing results and has the same drawbacks (I know this can be fixed, but the drawbacks remain):

```
Plot[{f@x, g@x + 4}, {x, 1, Length@l}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Abs[g[x] - g[x + .01]] < 0.05],
     Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

So: Is there a better (ie. more robust and natural) way to manage the exclusions in these cases?

**Credits**

To Heike and Szabolcs for their unbelievable useful  [`torn()`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/193) and [`upload palette`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/155/193) respectively.

**Edit**

Please note that the following is not what I want, since it requires previous knowledge of the function build up:

```
g[t_] = D[f[t], t];
Plot[{f@x, g[x] + 4}, {x, 1, Length@l}, Exclusions -> l, Evaluated -> True]
```

In any case it is irrelevant, since it doesn't work either

**Edit 2**

After a [conversation with @Rojo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5460201#5460201) about this, we (he) came up to the following interesting conclusion: **`Plot[]` detects exclusions only when it can manipulate the functions symbolically**. Just look at this:

```
iPN[x_?NumberQ] := IntegerPart[x];
Framed[GraphicsRow[Plot[#, {x, 0, 3}] & /@ {IntegerPart[x], iPN[x]}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Which by the way is strongly linked to my other question: [**What does “suitable for symbolic manipulation” in the documentation mean?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/what-does-suitable-for-symbolic-manipulation-in-the-documentation-mean)

Moreover, you can see that `Plot[]` employs the same effort exploring the discontinuities for both functions, albeit the `Exclusions` results are different.

```
data = Reap[ Plot[ #, {x, 1, 7}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, #}]] ][[-1,1]] & /@ 
                                                          {IntegerPart[x], iPN[x]};
p = Framed@GraphicsRow[ListPlot[#, Filling -> Axis] & /@ data]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Most probably because _Mathematica_ does not know that it is discontinuous. `Limit[g[t], t -> 4, Direction -> #] & /@ {1, -1}`

Comment: @R.M Yep, that was my first try :D

Comment: You could have done `g = f'`, y'know... :)

Comment: Anyway, for clarity: you want a routine that automagically detects jump discontinuities, or is it kosher for the user to tell the routine where to cut up the plot?

Comment: Your second "solution" could be done slightly more cleanly, though: `Plot[{f[x], g[x] + 4}, {x, 1, Length[l]}] /. Line[l_List?MatrixQ, rest___] :> Line[Split[l, Abs[Apply[Divide, Reverse[#2 - #1]]] < 10 &], rest]`

Comment: @belisarius, you wouldn't be satisfied with your solution with `//.` but making the slope threshold relative to the `PlotRange` (and maybe also the `AspectRatio`)?

Comment: You could use this as a slope threshold multiplier `{AspectRatio, PlotRange} /. AbsoluteOptions[p1, {AspectRatio, PlotRange}] /. {ar_, pl_} :> ar Divide @@ Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ pl`

Comment: @J.M. What I'd prefer is to be able to automagically use the Plot "interesting point detection routine" for detecting the discontinuities http://i.stack.imgur.com/PRoYZ.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have

```
l = {5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5};
f = Interpolation@l;
g[t_] = D[f[t], t];
p1 = Plot[{f@x, g@x + 4}, {x, 1, Length@l}, Evaluated -> True, 
  Exclusions -> True]
```

and your plot

```
plot = Plot[{f@x, g[x] + 4}, {x, 1, 7}, Evaluated -> True];
```

I suggest

```
With[{multiplier = {AspectRatio, PlotRange} /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[plot, {AspectRatio, PlotRange}] /. {ar_, pl_} :> 
     ar Divide @@ Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ pl}, 
  (plot //. 
   Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, b___}] /; 
     Abs[(y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)] > 10/multiplier :> {Line[{a, {x1, y1}}],
      Line[{{x2, y2}, b}]})
 ]
```

With your second suggestion, one gets the same resulting image

```
plot //. 
     Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, b___}] /; Abs[(y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)] > 10 -> 
    {Line[{a, {x1, y1}}], Line[{{x2, y2}, b}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However it breaks by just changing the scales:

```
plot = Plot[1000. {f@x, g[x] + 4}, {x, 1, 7}, Evaluated -> True];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Incorporating the multiplyer, for this second example, one gets

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps it would be smart to also add a condition not to filter vertical lines that are too short (relative to the plot range)

Comment: Hi Rojo! Thanks for your answer, see update.