# Rules governing Plot line generation

Tags: plotting, graphics

I was looking at the Documentation Center for `Round`, `Ceiling` and `Floor` when I noticed that the plots for `Round` showed some variation, even at the small size that the Documentation Center displays them, when blown up... well:

```
Plot[Round[x, 10], {x, -30, 30}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Rounding at 10]

```
Plot[Round[x], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Rounding at 1]

This intrigued me, I don't fully understand the rules governing generation of plots from functions.  Clearly the method is adaptive, generating more data points where there is "activity," but is the (dis)continuity just based on the resolution that the plot is generated using?

Any insight is welcome.

Comment: You get a similar result if you use `Round[x,1]`. This uses 163 points, the same as `Round[x,10]` whereas without, it uses 175 points. You'll find some general info on how the points are chosen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4572266)

Comment: note also Round[x] and Round[x,1] result in differenc evaluaiton points.  How do you get those markers?

Comment: @george2079 If you repeatedly click on the plot, you'll select individual lines in the graphics editing tool

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a complete answer. `Plot` attempts at some point to detect discontinuities symbolically. With a few built-ins, it can do it. `Round[x]` is an example but for some reason `Round[x, 1]` is not

Those discontinuities are excluded from the plots (see `Exclusions`)

So, for example, compare the output of these

```
Plot[Round[x], {x, -3, 3}]
Plot[Round[x, 1], {x, -3, 3}]
```

If you define `r[x_?NumericQ]:=Round[x]`, then `r[x]` behaves the same way as `Round[x, 1]` because it doesn't know how to manipulate your custom `r` symbolically

Now, if `Plot` already knows beforehand it has a discontinuity somewhere, it can be smarter than usual. For example, it can try to make the discontinuities sharper by sampling right on the sides.

```
x1 = Reap[
     Plot[Round[x, 1], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis, 
      EvaluationMonitor -> Sow[x]]][[-1, 1]] // Rest;
x2 = Reap[
     Plot[Round[x], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis, 
      EvaluationMonitor -> Sow[x]]][[-1, 1]] // Rest;
Complement[x2, x1]
```

> {-2.50191, -2.49809, -1.50191, -1.49809, -0.501913, -0.498087, \
>   0.498087, 0.501913, 1.49809, 1.50191, 2.49809, 2.50191}

As to the rendering issues with the `Filling`, that's because it excludes discontinuities by default. Try with `Exclusions->None`

```
Plot[Round[x], {x, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

Related question: [Managing Exclusions in Plot[ ]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8576/109)

Comment: So it's all in how the system is handling the exclusions that are generated by `Round[x]` but not in `Round[x,1]` ?  Considering that they are supposed to be equivalent expressions:

`Round[x]`=`Round[x, 1]`
`Round[x_,round_:1]:=`

I guess I'm curious to know what Wolfram implemented to have it handle that way.  Sigh, the never-ending depths of Mathematica's mysteries...

Comment: The link you included was very helpful in understanding the "interesting point detection" methodology that Mathematica employs and a little bit about it's exclusion detection method (thanks to your input it appears).  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @MRN16 glad to help, thanks for the accept

Comment: V9 computes exclusions for the two-argument form of `Round`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two excellent threads on StackOverflow that explore the inner workings of `Plot` sampling:

[Answer from Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572266/618728)

[Answer from Alexey Popkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7243229/618728)

One can get linear sampling by using the option `MaxRecursion -> 0`, and control the sampling rate with `PlotPoints`:

```
Plot[Round[x, 10], {x, -30, 30},
 Filling -> Axis,
 Mesh -> All, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> 80
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the links, I sometimes forget that the Mathematica questions can be found in the other stack websites too.