# Problem with high parameter values in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I tried to plot the following function as a Parametric Plot. When I include values for w up to 1 the plot looks fine, but I need this plot for values up to 100 or 1000.

```
z[w_, L_, re_, r1_, c1_, r2_, WoR_, WoT_, WoP_, c2_] = 
     I w L + 1/(1/(I w c1) + 1/r1) + re + 
      1/(1/(I w c2) + 1/r2 + 
         1/(WoR*Coth[(I*WoT* w)^WoP]/(I*WoT* w)^WoP))
```

I want to have a Nyquist-Plot, so I plotted Real and Imaginary-Part with the following command:

```
ParametricPlot[{
   Re[z[w, 5.1867*10^(-7), 0.10549, 0.014394, 1.699, 
     0.0098142, 5.5173*10^(-7), 7.428*10^(-13), 0.19962, 0.085349]], 
   Im[z[w, 5.1867*10^(-7), 0.10549, 0.014394, 1.699, 
     0.0098142, 5.5173*10^(-7), 7.428*10^(-13), 0.19962, 
     0.085349]]}, {w, 0.000001, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.098, 0.13}, {-0.004, 0.01}}]
```

This works fine.

When I replace `{w,0.000001,1}` with `{w,0.000001,1000}` I get a weird plot.

Unfortunately I have no idea where the problem could be, so I posted the whole example. I think that there might be some numerical problem that is responsible for the weird edges in the second plot. For small w like 0.00001 the graph is not correct either, it should become negative.

Comment: You don't need `ComplexExpand` in the plot

Comment: Oh, I thought I needed that because Im does not work for symbolic expressions. But the plotting evaluates it... I will delete that. Does not solve the problem though.

Comment: For your reference, there is a new function [NyquistPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NyquistPlot.html) in Mathematica 9.

Comment: Does setting the option `MaxRecursion -> Infinity` for `ParametricPlot` solve your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE and thank you for formatting your question properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add [`MaxRecursion -> 15`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxRecursion.html)<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11142/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482/121)</sup> to smooth out the line and `Evaluated -> True`<sup>[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7832/121),[(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7561/121)</sup> to speed evaluation.  I also modified the code so that `z` is only called once and then passed to each `Re` and `Im`.

```
ParametricPlot[
 {Re@#, Im@#} & @ 
  z[w, 5.1867*10^(-7), 0.10549, 0.014394, 1.699, 0.0098142, 5.5173*10^(-7), 
   7.428*10^(-13), 0.19962, 0.085349],
 {w, 0.000001, 1000},
 PlotRange -> {{0.098, 0.13}, {-0.004, 0.01}},
 Evaluated -> True,
 MaxRecursion -> 15
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 btw I would prefer `Through[{Re, Im}[...]]`.

Comment: @Silvia Thanks for the vote.  I know some prefer that but as a fan of terse coding I like `{Re@#, Im@#} &` a little better.  It's good you posted that though as I'm sure anyone who has not seen `Through` before will be glad.

Comment: Yes, it's just a personal preference. Those `#&@` things make me feel some kind of emotional instability :)

Comment: @Silvia My code does [sometimes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2804/121) have that effect on people. (See comments.)

Comment: Now that really scared me!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mr.Wizard, that helps! But still the curve does not look the way I expected it. With another program (Zplot) I get completely different results. Is it possible that I have some numerical issues here with the cotangens hyperbolicus or something?

Comment: @Apatura I'm sorry, I did not see your comment until now.  If you have not already solved the problem please explain the difference and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

**It helps to parameterize the function so that the path is traced out at a fairly constant speed.**  Let's compute and plot the speed:

```
f[w_] := z[w, 5.1867*10^(-7), 0.10549, 0.014394, 1.699, 0.0098142, 
  5.5173*10^(-7), 7.428*10^(-13), 0.19962, 0.085349];
g[w_] := Evaluate @ D[f[w], w];
Plot[Norm[g[w]], {w, 10^-5, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Plot]

**Therein lies the problem**: the speed undergoes a dramatic deceleration well before `w` even reaches $1$.  *Mathematica* has trouble determining an appropriate "time" scale for constructing this plot.  (Consequently, the usual expedients such as increasing the plot points or amount of recursive partitioning will have limited effects.)

**One cure is to reparameterize the curve.**  In principle, any differentiable curve can be reparameterized to have constant speed: that's ideal.  But we only need to roughly approximate this ideal, so let's just take a stab with a strongly nonlinear function, such as an exponential.  It's easy enough to work out the effect on the speed, but let's just dumbly start over with `w` replaced by `Exp[w]`, pretending we don't know how to differentiate:

```
g[w_] := Evaluate @ D[f[Exp[w]], w];
Plot[Norm[g[w]], {w, Log[.000001], Log[1000]}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Replot]

Now that is perfectly fine: there are swings in the speed, to be sure, but soon it settles down to a constant.  Let's exploit this in the plot, replacing the old parameter `w` by `Exp[w]`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Through[{Re[#] &, Im[#] &}[f[Exp[w]]]], {w, Log[10^-6], Log[10^6]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.098, 0.13}, {-0.004, 0.01}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, Hue[t]]]
```

[image: Parametric plot]

The hue provides a qualitative indication of the value of the corresponding parameter at each point, `Exp[w]`.  The extremely low speeds at the outset have compressed the reds and oranges down almost to a point at the beginning (left) of the curve, but after that the graphic evolved just fine and *Mathematica*--guided by the *typical* speeds in this parameterization--has done a good job without any additional prompting.