# Problem with large values in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I've got a question quite similar to No 18163:[Problem with high parameter values in ParametricPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18163/problem-with-high-parameter-values-in-parametricplot), but the solution of that problem did not work for me. So I hope you may have another tip.

I want to plot an equation similar (just a bit more difficult) then the following, the parameter and data range of concern is also similar:

$\omega = 2 c \pi / \lambda$,

where $c$ is the speed of light.

Now, the other function is a bit more tricky, therefore I want to use `ParametricPlot` and not `Plot`. My problem however is that it does not display the x-axis (or it might be so small I don't see it) when I use the correct value for `c`. It seems to be a problem with the large values, as everything is OK if I set `c = 2` or `c = 10` instead.

The code I used is:

1)

```
ParametricPlot[{(2 π)/λ, (2 π)/λ*1000}, {λ, 300, 1000}]
```

2)

```
ParametricPlot[{(2 π)/λ, (2 π])/λ*1000}, {λ, 300, 1000}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.010, 0.02}, {10^15, 10^16}}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 15,
  Evaluated -> True]
```

I tried to apply a workaround, creating a list to `Map` over the range $\lambda$ = 300 .. 1000 and then using `ListPlot`. This would work; however, it's not so good for my full problem.

Comment: Have you tried `AspectRatio`?

Comment: @Xerxes That's a great solution.  By default `ParametricPlot` tries to keep common scales on all axes; when the coordinates differ radically in size, that default needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 3):

Following the comments of Xerxes and whuber:

The default value for `AspectRatio` in `ParametricPlot` is:

```
OptionValue[ParametricPlot, AspectRatio]
(* Automatic *).
```

This differs from the one for `Plot`:

```
OptionValue[Plot, AspectRatio]
(* 1/GoldenRatio *)
```

Usually, this is a good choice as parametric plots usually have identical distances along the axes (this is what `Automatic` does). In your case, there is a huge difference between the two axes:

```
ParametricPlot[{(2 π)/λ, (2 π)/λ*1000}, {\λ, 300, 1000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution is to set `AspectRatio` to a value that looks good, like the value for `Plot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{(2 π)/λ, (2 π)/λ*1000}, {λ, 300, 1000}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]