# Plot and Parametric plot give different results

Tags: plotting, evaluation

```
f[k_] = {{-0.001 - 2 I k, 1, -0.001, -0.501}, {0.001, -0.5 - I k, 0.001, 0.001},
         {-0.001, -0.501, -0.001 + 2 I k, 1.}, {0.001, 0.001, 0.001, -0.5 + I k}};

x[k_] = Re[Eigenvalues[f[k]][[3]]];
Plot[x[k], {k, -1, 1}]
ParametricPlot[{k, x[k]}, {k, -1, 1}]
```

Why does `Plot` give a result, but `ParametricPlot` does not? Both functions are supposed to give the graph of the function `x[k]`. 
  I don't understand why `ParametricPlot` returns nothing. Please help me to get the difference.

Comment: It's because the aspectratio is bad in parametricplot

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20854/57

Comment: @Sjoerd It seems to me this may be considered a duplicate.  Any reason you did not vote to close it as such?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wasn't near my PC, so I couldn't check what *"Why does Plot give a result, but ParametricPlot does not?"* entailed. I assumed it would be like the linked question, but wasn't sure. Will vote to close now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[x[k], {k, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the `ParametricPlot` you need to alter the `Options` to reproduce the plot.

```
ParametricPlot[{k, x[k]}, {k, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

You can find out the default `AspectRatio` for `Plot` by doing:

```
Options[Plot, AspectRatio]
```

> {AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR more elegantly as suggested by Belisarius

```
p = Plot[x[k], {k, -1, 1}];
ParametricPlot[{k, x[k]}, {k, -1, 1}, Evaluate[AbsoluteOptions[p]]]
```

Comment: `p = Plot[x[k], {k, -1, 1}];
ParametricPlot[{k, x[k]}, {k, -1, 1}, Evaluate[AbsoluteOptions[p]]]`

Comment: @Belisarius. Nice