# What algorithm does Plot use to determine abscissas?

Tags: plotting, implementation-details

(I'm hoping this question is not hopelessly naive...)

My understanding is that `Plot`'s strategy is to generate a list of abscissas, evaluate the argument expression at those abscissas, and from that point on behave pretty much like ListPlot with the list of abscissa-ordinate pairs as input.  (More or less.)

Assuming that the sketch above is not fantastically off-base, what algorithm does `Plot` use to compute the list of abscissas to use?

Comment: `ListLinePlot @@@ (Reap@Plot[Sow[x] x, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @belisarius: interesting trick, thanks, but I confess that I don't feel much more capable of guessing *Mathematica*'s algorithm for generating the mesh than I was before...

Comment: Mma algorithms are usually proprietary (except when they disclose them explicitly) and usually not easy to guess from the behavior

Comment: @belisarius: Yeah, that's what I was alluding to with my opening parenthetical remark...  Your comment basically tells me that, yep, my question was pretty naive...  I guess I was hoping to find something like "Mathematica's algorithm is based on a fourth-order Craske-Trump adaptive bisection algorithm, but it has been enhanced with many proprietary modifications..."

Comment: I'm hoping to see a strategy based on curvature.

Comment: a more interesting varient on belisarius suggestion: ListPlot[Reap[Plot[Sow[x]; 1/(x - .5)^2, {x, 0, 1}]][[2, 1]]]. You can see that there is an adaptive curvitue based algorithm.  Oddly it seems to never eval at the lower bound..

Comment: Is your question answered by the posts linked here?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11142/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: That link leads to quite a lode of insight on `Plot`'s ways...  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question, but might help you with your investigations...

By setting the system option `"VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}` you get all sorts of information printed about the plotting process. The code below intersperses that output with the actual sampled points (shown as `ListPlot`s), showing the initial sampling and multiple refinement steps. There are numerical parameters associated with the refinement steps - they mean nothing to me but perhaps an expert could infer something about the algorithm.

```
plotinfo[func_, {from_, to_}] := Module[{a, f, g},
  SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}];
  a = SplitBy[Reap[Block[{Print = Sow[f[##]] &},
       Plot[func[x], {x, from, to}, EvaluationMonitor :>
         Sow[g[{x, func[x]}]]]]][[2, 1]], Head];
  SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> False}];
  a[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2]] = f@ListPlot[#, Filling -> Axis] & /@ a[[2 ;; -1 ;; 2, All, 1]];
  a /. f -> Print;]
```

The arguments are a function to plot and a range, e.g.

```
plotinfo[Tan, {0, 10}]
```

This is just a snippet of the full output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This was a beautiful answer.