# Plot, extract data to a file

Tags: plotting, export

I need to save data that *Mathematica* uses inside the `Plot` command. The format that I would like to have is:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
.....
```

i.e. basically, two columns, *x* and *y* (sorted, if possible) so that I can use the data for other programs.

I already played with `Export` and got the data enclosed in `{}` and tons of other information I don't need: color, axis, *etc.*

What is the nicest way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Related: [(14222)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14222/121)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First you need to get the data from your `Plot`.  Two methods are extraction with patterns:

```
data = Cases[Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];
```

and `EvaluationMonitor`:

```
data =
 Reap[
   Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin@x}]]
 ][[2, 1]];
```

I prefer the first method's brevity and the fact that it can be used on existing `Graphics` output by `Plot`.

Then you just need to `Export` the `data` in the right format:

```
Export["file.txt", data, "Table"]
```

---

A somewhat more interesting example is saving data from a multi-line plot:

```
gr = Plot[{Sin@x, Cos@x, Sinc@x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The expression assigned to `gr` is a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) object which has the form:

> Graphics[*primitives*, *options*]

We are interested in the data that makes up the primitives, therefore we will operate on `First @ gr`.  We will also not restrict the `Cases` to find only the first match as was done above (the fourth argument of `Cases`).

```
multidat = Cases[First @ gr, Line[data_] :> data, -4];
```

We could then export each part to a separate file like this:

```
Export["file" <> IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #, "Table"] & ~MapIndexed~ multidat
```

> ```
> {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"}
> ```

---

It should be pointed out that if you do not require the [adaptive sampling of `Plot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11133/121) you can generate your data more simply and directly using `Table`, e.g.:

```
Table[{x, Sin@x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.01}]
```

---

## 3D Plots

[jheidk51](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/67126/jheidk51) asks: "How can this be generalised for 3D plots?"

This depends on the format of the plot.  In the simplest case of a single formal function (one z value per x,y pair) we can just pull all the points from [`GraphicsComplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html):

```
gr3D = Plot3D[x^2*Cos[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}];

points = FirstCase[p3D, GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> p, {}, -4];

ListPlot3D[points]
```

[image]

However in plots with multiple surfaces the points will be mixed and jumbled.  They are still valid points as shown with [`ListPointPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) but attempted surface plots will be a mess.

```
gr3Dmulti = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 
    4 + Sin[v]}, {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 
    4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
points = FirstCase[gr3Dmulti, GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> p, {}, -4];

ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

We can convert `GraphicsComplex` expressions to explicit coordinates using [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html), then split elements by [`GraphicsGroup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGroup.html) and extract [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) coordinates:

```
poly = 
   Cases[
      Normal[gr3Dmulti], 
      GraphicsGroup[g_] :>
         Cases[g, Polygon[p_, __] :> p, -4],
      -5
   ];
```

These polygon coordinates can be used to reconstruct the plot:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Orange, Polygon @ poly[[1]], Cyan, Polygon @ poly[[2]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue with NDSolve graph and I was looking for just 2 colums of pure numbers. This helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I understand the use of levelspec -4, but puzzlingly, in the example the pattern allows this to work too: `Cases[First@gr, Line[data_] :> data, -1]`

Comment: @Chris Don't be puzzled.  I normally use `-1` with such patterns, but recently I've been trying to be more specific with my level specifications which in some cases makes a significant difference in speed as fewer expressions are scanned wastefully.  In this case it doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: What are exactly these values Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]]; that are shown in mathematica??i have to extract values from a plot of a pretty complicated function and these informations are very important to me..thanks in advance!

Comment: @stathis I am not sure I understand.  Are you asking about that adaptive sampling that *Mathematica* uses?  You can see the points used by adding the option `Mesh -> All` to `Plot`.

Comment: How can this be generalised  for 3D plots?

Comment: @jheidk51 I extended my answer to address this.  Let me know if you have any problems or further questions.