# LogLinearPlot, extact data to a file, part 2

Tags: plotting, export

My question is based on the discussion that I started: [Plot, extract data to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file/19861#19861)

The method proposed works well for the `Plot` command, but what about `LogLinearPlot`? This was the original motivation when I started the thread. I wanted to extract the data for `LogLinearPlot`, because I wanted a tighter grid for r $\approx$ 0. Otherwise, I could have just used `Table` and wouldn't have started the thread. This doesn't work with `Table`, which produces a uniform grid.

Anyways, this is my code:

```
LogLinearPlot[{f[r]*r, 0}, {r, 0.0001, 1000}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.2}, MaxRecursion -> 15]
data = Cases[%, Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];
Export["~/Desktop/1.dat", SetAccuracy[%, 10], Alignment -> Center]
```

*The catch is that it produces a relative positions of the points on the **r** axis for the 1st column (**r** coordinates of the points they would have if the **r**-axis wasn't set to be logarithmic on the plot).*

For example,

```
-9.210340043    -0.044128619
-9.210320733    -0.04412862
 ......
```

whereas I was expecting something like this:

```
 0.000110000    -0.044128619
 0.000170000    -0.04412862
 ........
```

The origin of the "fictitious" and  real axes coincide. How do I get the actual values of **r**?

Comment: Your attempt to use the `Plot[]` mesh, although achievable, doesn't seem justified. You could design your own "meshing" algorithm, fitted specifically to your problem.

Comment: I posted an answer showing how to adapt both of the methods I previously gave.  In the future consider mentioning your *actual use* in questions as that will help answers to be better on target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to to invert the Log operation that is done on the $x$ data, with [`Exp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exp.html):

```
gr = LogLinearPlot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 10}]

data = Cases[gr[[1]], Line[data_] :> data, -4][[1]];

data = {Exp@#, #2} & @@@ data;

ListLogLinearPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Alternatively you could use [the other method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19860/121), which may be simpler in this case:

```
{gr, {data}} =
  Reap[
   LogLinearPlot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 10}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin@x}]]
  ];

gr

ListLogLinearPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]