# How to extract data from a contour plot to a text file?

Tags: plotting

I have the following expression from which I want to extract data for a contour plot.

```
a = (r^2/2 + (r BesselI[1, 2 r])/(
 2 BesselI[0, 
   2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])])) (1.386371389484812` + 
 0.4367320268554276` (2.289733608959785` - 
    0.7936052912509126` (1 + 0.24` z + 
       0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2) + (-45.44` BesselI[0, 
      2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])] - 
    4 (1.386371389484812` + 
       0.4367320268554276` (2.289733608959785` - 
          0.7936052912509126` (1 + 0.24` z + 
             0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2) + 
       0.346592847371203` (1 + 0.24` z + 
          0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2) (4 BesselI[1, 
         2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])] (1 + 0.24` z + 
          0.2` Sin[6.2834` z]) - 
       4 BesselI[0, 
         2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])] (1 + 0.24` z + 
          0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2))/(4 (BesselI[1, 
       2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])] - 
      4 BesselI[0, 
        2 (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])] (1 + 0.24` z + 
         0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2)) + 
 0.346592847371203` (1 + 0.24` z + 0.2` Sin[6.2834` z])^2);     

ContourPlot[a, {z, 0, 1.5}, {r, 3, 5.5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 180, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> {Thickness[0.0005]}, 
  Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> {Thickness[0.0005]}, ContourShading -> False]
```

The output should be a text file.

Comment: Related: [(19859)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19859/121)

Comment: Sorry for Typing here. Actually, I asked this question on the main page but didn't get some appropriate answer for it. My question is quite related to here. I used all these methods mentioned in the answers for extracting data from my ContourPlot. but it's not working for me. I want the output in a text file. F = 0.025; kv = 0.0043; kw = 0.046; A = (F + kv); B = (F + kw); Du = 290; Dv = 61.443; Dw = 7.3; G = (F - Sqrt[F^2 - 4*F*(A^2 + B^2)])^2; j11 = (-((4*F^2*(A^2 + B^2))*G^(-1)) - F); j12 = -(2*A); j13 = -(2*B); j21 = (4*A^2*F^2)/(G); j22 = (A); j31 = (4*B^2*F^2)/G; j33 = B; C1 = (k^2 (Du +

Comment: @Albert Please don't use answers as a follow-up questions. If a specific method does not work for you please create a question, include all relevant code, possibly the most reduced example, explain what exactly are you expecting and why current result does not fit your needs. There was no export part in your example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Original answer

For getting points of individual lines one can use `Normal`:

```
points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_, ___] :> pts, Infinity];
```

(I assumed here that each `Line` primitive contains exactly one line, as it is true for the current `ContourPlot` implementation. Generally, a `Line` primitive can contain several lines and for this case this code should be rewritten, for example:

```
points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_, ___] :> Flatten[pts, Depth[pts] - 3], Infinity];
```

)

To convert this list of lists of points into multicolumn table one can use:

```
multicolumnTable = Flatten /@ Flatten[PadRight[points, Automatic, ""], {2}];
```

Here is how it looks:

```
TableForm[multicolumnTable[[;; 10, ;; 6]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Flatten@Array[{x@#, y@#} &, Length[points]]}]
```

[image: table]

Exporting the multicolumn table:

```
Export["table.tsv", multicolumnTable]
```

---

### Extracting the values of the objective function (per request in comments)

The 2D `Graphics` object generated by `ContourPlot` does not necessarily contain information on the values of the objective function (Z-coordinate). The only source of this information are contour labels which are generated according to the `ContourLabels` option. With the default value `ContourLabels->Automatic` each contour is wrapped by `Tooltip` with second argument being the contour label providing information on the value of the objective function. In the current `ContourPlot` implementation the label is simply a number and the contour is one or more `Line` primitives each containing exactly one actual line. Assuming that the plot does not contain any other `Tooltip`s, it is straightforward to extract the data:

```
points = Flatten[
   Cases[Normal@plot, 
    Tooltip[contour_, label_] :> 
     Cases[contour, l_Line :> ArrayPad[First@l, {{0}, {0, 1}}, label]], 
    Infinity], 1];
multicolumnTable = Flatten /@ Flatten[PadRight[points, Automatic, ""], {2}];
TableForm[multicolumnTable[[;; 10, ;; 6]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Flatten@Array[{x@#, y@#, z@#} &, Length[points]]}]
Export["table.tsv", multicolumnTable]
```

[image: table]

Comment: This is working fine. THx to you and to Nasser.

Comment: how to treat the contourplot as a 3D plot and extract the data having three columns with r, z, and a(r,z)?

Comment: @MMM What you want is generally impossible to achieve because the `Graphics` object generated by `ContourPlot` not necessarily contains information on the values of the objective function. The only place where it can be is created by `ContourLabels` function which is (in general) arbitrary.

Comment: @MMM Probably it would be simpler to use `Plot3D` with options `MeshFunctions->{#3&}, Mesh->5` and then apply the approach described in my answer for extracting the mesh lines. Everything should be the same with exception to the `TableForm` where instead of `Array[{x@#, y@#} &, Length[points]]` you should have `Array[{x@#, y@#, z@#} &, Length[points]]`.

Comment: @MMM But if you insist on using `ContourPlot` it is also possible to extract the values of the objective function when the default setting `ContourLabels->Automatic` is used (at least with the current implementation of `ContourPlot`). I'll add a method to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**

If you want the coordinates, then

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts__] :> pts, Infinity];
Export["data.txt", data[[1]]];

Dimensions[data[[1]]]
(* {55340, 2} *)
data[[1, 1 ;; 10, All]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

FullForm of the plot shows the `GraphicsComplex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and `GraphicsComplex` has this form

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Original answer*

```
plot = ContourPlot[a, {z, 0, 1.5}, {r, 3, 5.5}, PlotPoints -> 180, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ContourShading -> False];
data = Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["data.txt", data];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, @Nasser thx for your response. Its seems to me that the output is not in the correct format. The output should be in two columns r and z.

Comment: You asked for contour data. The above is the contour data. There are 11 rows. One for each contour.

Comment: You are right but I need to have the data in 2 columns format.

Comment: @MMM I do not follow you. Where did this 2 columns come from and what they represent? May be all what you needed then is a simple Table command. You have to be clear what is it you want as I am not really following you.

Comment: Let me try to make it clear, I want the data in following format.                 
r   z (say contour 1)             
r   z (say contour 2)                  
r   z (say contour 3)                      
Output in two columns for each contour. Clear?

Comment: I have used the Table command within Export but the data is in horizontal form. What I need is the data of each contour in a vertical form having two columns for r and z.

Comment: Is it clear now @Nasser?

Comment: Nasser, I think MMM is expecting coordinates. The output that you show is a list of numbers, not coordinates. Perhaps part of a GraphicsComplex?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries if the coordinates is what is needed, I updated the answer. thank you.