# How to superimpose contour lines on transformed image

Tags: image-processing

My goal is to

superimpose contours lines or contour plots on distance transformed image.

[image]

Comment: `DistanceTransform[]` has a few glitches, but it basically does what you want. What else do you want?

Comment: Just use an appropriate colorfunction for the distance transform... no need for ListContourPlot, I think.

Comment: @belisarius is anyway I can extract contour from listcontour plot.

Comment: There are  lot.For example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31870/193

Comment: @blisarius thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `DistanceFunction` where a complete contour always falls on the pixels, like `ManhattenDistance` you can directly work on the image. The approach is pretty simple, calculate the distance transform

```
horse = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCfWy.png"];
dist = DistanceTransform[horse, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];
```

And then you set all distances to 1 which have a certain remainder. So if I want to have the contours for distances 1,5,9,... you use

```
lines = Map[Boole[Mod[#, 4] == 1] &, Round@ImageData[dist], {2} ] // Image
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Superimposing is then as easy as laying the images over another, or using different color channels:

```
ColorCombine[{lines, dist // ImageAdjust, dist // ImageAdjust}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The big advantage of this method is that you don't need to *trace* the contour which makes is as fast as an eye-blink. The disadvantage is that it does not work for the natural `EuclideanDistance`.

Comment: @user12455 But this is not what you have asked in your question!

Comment: @user12455 No, edit your current question. Write up clearly what you try to achieve and what you already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Your image is taken from [`DistanceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistanceTransform.html) documentation page.

[image]

```
pic2 = ListContourPlot[ImageData[pic, DataReversed -> True], 
                       ContourShading -> None, Frame -> False, ContourStyle -> Yellow];

Show[ pic, pic2]
```

[image]