# Image partition according to contours

Tags: image-processing

I want to extract contours from following image or 
I am wondering how to partition following image:

line image looks like:

[image]

This question is linked: 
[How to superimpose contour lines on transformed image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42559/how-to-superimpose-contour-lines-on-transformed-image)

Comment: Would this help? `Colorize@MorphologicalComponents[
  ColorNegate@Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/agPO0.png"], 
  CornerNeighbors -> False]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/agPO0.png"];
(mc = MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[i], CornerNeighbors -> False]) // Colorize
Grid@Partition[ Image /@ (Replace[mc, Except[#] -> 0, {2}] & /@ Range@Max@mc), 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]