# Using implicit region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, probability-or-statistics

So I have a Likelihood function (`Lk[x,y]`) that is a product of 4 different gaussian functions of different combinations of parameters (`x`,`xy`,`x/y` and `yx^4`). I need to find the compatibility of my results with a reference one. I'm traying to do in the 68% of volume way:

- Calculate the total volume integral (`T`) of the Likelihood in a significant region;
- Calculate a volume (`V`) from the maximum point to a certain level (say height `H`)
- Make the ratio `V/T` until it reaches ~0.68 and then check if the reference point is within the region

In order to determine what `{x,y}` points will be integrated (in the second step) I'm trying to use `ImplicitRegion[Lk[x,y] >= H*Lk[xM,yM],{x,y}]`. In other words, I want the `{xi,yi}` tuples such that `Lk{xi,yi}` are greater than a portion of the maximum (0 < H < 1). My problem apparently lies on my implementation in this ImplicitRegion. Probably I'm misunderstading something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that `ImplicitRegion` can handle such complicated conditions. Maybe a better way would be to use `ContourPlot` or `Plot3D` with `MeshFunctions->{#3&}` and extract the contours from the plot. If I'll have time later I'll write a solution

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31858/how-to-extract-data-from-a-contour-plot-to-a-text-file) for extracting the contours from a plot