# ContourPlot - export data points

Tags: plotting

Right now I have troubles exporting the data out of my contour plot.

Following is the code and the `ContourPlot`:

```
M = 1000000;
d = 0.0005;

p[cp_, g_] := Sqrt[(2*Pi*g*M/1716)^2 - (2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2];
q[cp_, g_] := Sqrt[(2*Pi*g*M/785)^2 - (2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2];



sy[cp_, g_, p_, 
  q_] := (((2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2 - q^2)^2) Cos[p*d] Sin[q*d] + 
  4 ((2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2 ) p q Sin[p*d] Cos[q*d]
sy[cp_, g_] := sy[cp, g, p[cp, g], q[cp, g]];

as[cp_, g_, p_, 
  q_] := (((2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2 - q^2)^2) Sin[p*d] Cos[q*d] + 
  4 ((2*Pi*g*M/(cp))^2 ) p q Cos[p*d] Sin[q*d]
as[cp_, g_] := as[cp, g, p[cp, g], q[cp, g]];

ContourPlot[ {sy[cp, g]/q[cp, g] == 0, as[cp, g]/p[cp, g] == 0}, {g, 
  0.001, 0.1}, {cp, 0.01, 2000}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: the plotted functions]

There is already a posting regarding a similar topic, but I have problems to adapt this to my problem: 
[How to extract data from a contour plot to a text file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31858/how-to-extract-data-from-a-contour-plot-to-a-text-file/31870#31870)

I hope somebody can help or guide me to the correct source.

Comment: Do you want to extract the interpolated points that are used to generate the plot?

Comment: @kglr thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use `FullForm` on the plot itself, and look at the first significant heads, we see that it's just a `Graphics` object composed of a `GraphicsComplex` object.

```
plot = ContourPlot[ {sy[cp, g]/q[cp, g] == 0, as[cp, g]/p[cp, g] == 0}, {g, 0.001, 0.1}, {cp, 0.01, 2000}, PlotPoints -> 100]

{#[[1, 0]], #[[1, 1, 0]]} &@FullForm@plot
```

> {Graphics, GraphicsComplex}

Then we can use `Normal` on the first part of the plot (The `GraphicsComplex`), to get something in the familiar `Graphics` format.

```
{{},{},{Hue[0.67,0.6,0.6],Line[{<<1>>}]},{Hue[0.906068,0.6,0.6],Line[{{0.001,50.2764},{0.00100432,50.4276},<<934>>,{0.0997525,439.451},{0.1,439.876}}]}}
```

But we don't want all the color options and other aesthetics, we just want the points that are connected by `Line` objects.

```
Cases[%, Line[pts_] :> pts, \[Infinity]]
```

> {{{0.1,1392.03},{0.0999058,1392.04},{0.099875,1392.04},{0.0998437,1392.05},{0.09975,1392.05},<<1421>>,{0.00125,1396.09},{0.00113784,1396.21},{0.00109769,1395.92},{0.001,1396.09}},{<<1>>,<<937>>}}

Or all together

```
FullForm@plot
Normal@%[[1]] (*// Short[#, 1] &*)
pts = Cases[%, Line[pts_] :> pts, \[Infinity]] (*// Short[#, 2] &*)
```

Then to export the data in an easily usable file, we simply use

```
SetDirectory["Your_Directory"]
pts >> "data.m"
ListPlot@<< "data.m"
```

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you very much!
I need some more time to understand it fully, but it works!

Comment: @Yasya You're welcome. And if you're satisfied, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: As I undersand right now, you showed how to export the interpolated points?

Comment: @Yasya Yes, I chose to use `Get` and `Put` with a `Package` file (.m), but there are [many](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) [ways](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html) to save/export in many different formats in _Mathematica_.

Comment: i am not sure, if i should open a new thread on this topic: i am still failing to find a way to export the data in a way, that i can import in octave.