# Export a plot to Excel

Tags: list-manipulation, excel

I know questions similar to this have been asked before but I couldn't figure it out.
These are my hypothetical lines:

```
g[x_] = r*x^2 + 2

f[y_] := NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 0, 1000}]

Plot[f[x], {r, 0, 10}]
```

Then I get a plot. What I want is to simply export the x and y values of this plot to excel. So I do:

```
Export["out.xlsx", Table[f[x], {r, 0, 10}]]
```

but it only exports the y (aka f[x] values). How can I get the x values as well?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Much appreciated Edmund.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot, extract data to a file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file)