# How to Extract data points from plot in mathematica to redraw it with another program?

Tags: plotting

Since I do not like the style of the Mathematica plots, I prefer to extract the data points and use other programs to get publish quality plots.

[Plot, extract data to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file)

In this page, it is explained how to extract data points from already drawn figure in Mathematica. However, this command does not work if the function is piecewise continous. For instance;

```
data = Cases[Plot[Tan@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];

Export["file.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Then the extracted data is up to pi/2 , to the part where the function diverges.

Is there a way to get all the data points that is drawn with Mathematica to get the exact same plot with other programs?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: The plots in *Mathematica* are extremely customizable. Have you considered tweaking the many formatting options to create a style that suits you or using one of the many build in [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html)s? These too can be customized through the plot function's options.

Comment: With the possible exception of the typesetting component, I agree with @Edmund.  So ... maybe you could post an example of an aesthetic plot that you feel is hard to produce with WL.

Comment: This solves my problem. However, is there a way to get the output in the same format? All the x and y values with the same significant figures for instance.

Answer (score 17):

In your `Cases` command you specifically asked for only the first line.  You can grab all the lines, and `Catenate` the results into a single list

```
data = Catenate@
   Cases[Plot[Tan@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[data_] :> data, Infinity];
Export["file.txt", data, "Table"];
ListPlot[Import["file.txt", "Table"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative

```
points = Table[{x, Tan[x]}, {x, Range[0, 2 π, .01]}];

ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image]

```
Shallow[points]
```

> {{0., 0.}, {0.01, 0.0100003}, {0.02, 0.0200027}, {0.03, 
>     0.030009}, {0.04, 0.0400213}, {0.05, 0.0500417}, {0.06, 
>     0.0600721}, {0.07, 0.0701146}, {0.08, 0.0801711}, {0.09, 
>     0.0902438}, <<619>>}

So, **points** is your List, containing 600plus Values. And you can use your strategy to save'em:

```
Export["points.txt", points, "Table"]
```

Comment: Plot chooses its point adaptively, so your method will not yield the same point set.