# Getting different results form Tan[x] and Tan @ X

Tags: core-language

In the post [How to Extract data points from plot in mathematica to redraw it with another program?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125222/how-to-extract-data-points-from-plot-in-mathematica-to-redraw-it-with-another-pr?noredirect=1&lq=1), I found out `Tan @ x` and `Tan[x]` are generating different data on export. What the context under which `@` is used in Mathematica. For example, `Catenate @`, `Tan @ x` and `Sort @ Select`.

Comment: `Tan[x]` is the same as `Tan@x`, as well as `x//Tan`

Comment: `Tan[x]` is the same as `Tan@x`, so presumably your have an order of operations problem.  Try parentheses, or post simple code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: When a piece of code doesn't do what you expect it to, *always show an example in your question*.  See http://sscce.org/ for guidance on how to write a useful example.

Comment: @Feyre, Alan and Szabolcs, thanks a lot. My problem is now resolved.