# Is there a way to gather the points used in a Plot and generate a function that passes through those points?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, interpolation

like the title says: is that possible? In my case, I have a plot of an integral that is evaluated numerically. Maybe using Interpolate with the points used by mathematica to draw the graph or something?

Comment: Do you only have the plot? not the code making it?

Comment: These may be helpfule: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5364088/4712538, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125222/9490,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the plots

```
plts = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Extracting the sets of points from the plot

```
pts = Cases[plts, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
```

Interpolating each set of points

```
funcs = Interpolation /@ pts;
```

Plotting the interpolations for comparison

```
Plot[Evaluate[#[x] & /@ funcs], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Addressing the additional questions in the comments.

To evaluate one of the three functions at `x == 1` use `Part ( [[...]] )`. For example, to evaluate the second interpolated function

```
funcs[[2]][1]

(* 0.909298 *)
```

To integrate the product of each function with `Sin[x]` over the interval `{0, 1}`

```
NIntegrate[#[x]*Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}] & /@ funcs

(* {0.272675, 0.397216, 0.321925} *)
```

Or for a single function

```
NIntegrate[funcs[[2]][x]*Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]

(* 0.397216 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: how could I integrate the interpolated function?
Say I wanted to integrate func Sin[x] between x=0 and x=1, would the following code be correct? (func is like your funcs)

NIntegrate[Sin[x] Evaluate[#[x] & /@ func], {x,0,1}]