# Export Graph data in text format

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

How can we export the data in excel of the following streamlines and contour plots to plot in Tecplot?

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

and isotherms, contourplot

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x]+Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4Pi}]
```

Comment: `Cases[yourStreamPlot, a_Arrow :> a[[1]], All]` will return a list of the points describing each one of the arrows in that plot. You could export that to various formats using `Export`. It will then be up to you to adapt that so you can use Tecplot (with which I am not familiar). The `ContourPlot` is more complicated because color matters there, but if you just want the contour lines: `Cases[Normal@yourContourPlot, l_Line :> l[[1]], All]`. What do you need to do in Tecplot specifically? Maybe it could be accomplished in MMA without exporting.

Comment: Does StreamPlot not just use the derivative in the x and y direction? Could you not just export the data that way?

Comment: @Teabelly i Want to export the data results of fluid flow model. The code of that problem is too large that's why here I mention the simple example so I will get the idea of how to export the data?

Comment: Can you post the equation please?

Comment: @Teabelly Please check this code i want to export data of streamlines and isotherms.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WDH2PUMahuKMn1PtnaqYPSl1XCimgdXm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### StreamPlot - Using Excel

#### Preparing Data

Here is the procedure you should follow:

```
StreamPlot[{eq1[x,y], eq2[x,y]}, {x, ...}, {y, ...}]
```

should be written as:

```
Flatten[#, 1] &@ Table[{x, y, eq1[x,y], eq2[x,y]}, {x, ...}, {y, ...}]
```

Because writing on a single spreadsheet needs a 2-dimensional matrix, apply `Flatten` and export it as a `.xlsx` file (`.csv` also works):

```
data = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, -1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]


Export["D:\\data0.xlsx", data]
```

Open in Excel, select the data from the upper left-hand side to the other corner (direction of your selection is important for Tecplot add-in):

[image]

In Tecplot, change plot option from `XY Line` to `2D Cartesian`, enable `Vector`:

[image]

A dialog will pop up, choose `x3` for `U` and `x4` for `V`:

[image]

Now you have your plot in Tecplot (because of the `Table` all the vectors sit on a grid):

[image]

If you want to have more vectors, increase `Table` step size for variables:

```
data = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, -1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, .1}, {y, -3, 
    3, .1}]
```

[image]

If you want the same vectors you got in Mathematica:

```
eq[x_, y_] := {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2};
plt = StreamPlot[eq[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

Output:

[image]

Extract vectors from `plt` and apply `eq`:

```
data = Join[#, eq @@ #] & /@ 
  Cases[plt, Arrow[{x_, __}] -> x, Infinity]
```

Result:

[image]

### StreamPlot - Without Excel

You could export the data directly from Mathematica to a format which is known to Tecplot like `.dat` or `.plt`:

#### With `.dat` Format

Export data table to a `.dat` file:

```
Export["D:\\data1.dat", 
 Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, -1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], "PLT"]
```

Open Teplot, go to `File` > `Load Data...`, choose `D:\\data1.dat`, in `Choose Loader` dialog, choose `Tecplot Data Loader`:

[image]

Change plot option from `XY Line` to `2D Cartesian`, enable `Vector`. For the dialog, choose `v3` variable for `U` and `v4` for `V`:

#### With `.plt` Format

First, you need to define `.plt` export format for Mathematica:

```
ImportExport`RegisterExport["PLT", MyExportFormat`Exporter ]
MyExportFormat`Exporter[filename_, data_, opts___] :=
 Module[{edata, strm},
  edata = 
   "TITLE=\"Mathematica\"\nVARIABLES=" <> 
    StringReplace[
     ExportString[
      "v" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[1, #] &@Length@data[[1]], "TSV"], 
     "\n" -> " "] <>
    "\nZone T=\"M\"\n" <> ExportString[data, "TSV"];
  strm = OpenWrite[filename];
  WriteString[strm, edata];
  Close[strm]
  ]
```

Now we registered `PLT` export format.

Export your data with `PLT` format:

```
Export["D:\\data1.plt", 
 Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[{x, y, -1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], "PLT"]
```

Open the file in Teplot and follow the same procedure, you will get the same result like `.dat` format:

[image]

### ContourPlot

We will populate points and calculate their values, export them to Excel, use Tecplot Add-in to import them to Tecplot:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Output:

[image]

Use `Table` and add headings:

```
rg1 = Range[0, 4 Pi];
rg2 = Range[0, 4 Pi];

(* Data *)
Table[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, rg1}, {y, rg2}]

(* Data + headings *)
addHeadings = 
  MapThread[Prepend, {#, Prepend[rg1, ""]}] &@Prepend[#, rg2] &;

data4 = addHeadings@Table[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, rg1}, {y, rg2}];
```

Export the data:

```
Export["D:\\data4.xlsx", data4]
```

Open in Excel, select the data from the upper left-hand side to the other corner (direction of your selection is important for Tecplot add-in):

[image]

If you enable `Tecplot add-in` use `Send to Tecplot` under `Add-ins` Excel tab, when Tecplot opened, enable Contour:

[image]

Just like `StreamPlot`, increasing the `Table` variable step size, increase the quality of the result:

```
rg1 = Range[0, 4 Pi, .1];
rg2 = Range[0, 4 Pi, .1];
```

[image]

In the end, I should mention I'm not an expert in Tecplot and you might find better solutions, and if you do, don't remember to add it to this post so it becomes helpful for future viewers.

I used Mathematica 12.2 and Tecplot 360 EX 2017 R3.

Comment: @Bany Thank you so much for your help and for elaborating the problem in detail. It works.

Comment: how can export (    .dat) file of data

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what data you want, maybe this helps, it seems to give you the data for each vector field:

```
Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
Export["file.xls", %]
```

```
out[1]: {{{-13, -11}, {-12, -6}, {-11, -3},...}}
```

Can be used to produce the same graph... ish:

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
d0 = Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]

Export["file.txt", d0, "Table"]

ListVectorPlot[d0, StreamPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

If you want the data from a graph with unknown equation / origin, maybe check this out:

[How to Extract data points from plot in mathematica to redraw it with another program?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125222/how-to-extract-data-points-from-plot-in-mathematica-to-redraw-it-with-another-pr)

Comment: It's not working because when I export data the I can't plot it again in Mathematica or others like excel, Tecplot.

Comment: you can see the type of data that I export from comsol code. Please see this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHwbmb_E237BpN7xGuUpONnoJVWqGAFr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mathematicain I'm unfamilair with Tecplot, you want to export from mathematica in a similar format to the data in the link? Or you want to Import this data?

Comment: The {x,y} are the first two columns of the main table (corresponding to d0), can you not just identify this in Tecplot?

Comment: Yes I want to export data like the data I mention. in txt of xls format

Comment: how can we export data in xls format if want to plot in Tecplot or directly in Excel

Comment: Export["file.xls", d0] should work? You can either add headings in mathmatica or excel if that's the problem, if you want more data like the linked file you can also Append

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120545/discussion-between-teabelly-and-mathematicain).

Comment: To export into one sheet you can use: Export["sampledata.xlsx", {"d0" -> d0}]