# Extract data from an imported plot

Tags: plotting

I have a plot of an unknown function stored as a PNG file in a folder in which Mathematica file also is saved.
I have used

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]; 
importedplot = Import["plot.png"];
```

I am going to redraw it by `ListPlot` if I was able to extract data from this plot.

I have seen [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125222/how-to-extract-data-points-from-plot-in-mathematica-to-redraw-it-with-another-pr) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14222/getting-a-list-of-accurate-coordinates-from-a-plot) but I could not understand what must be replaced by for example `Plot[Tan@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]` in command

```
 data = Cases[Plot[Tan@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];

 Export["file.txt", data, "Table"]
```

As it used in the pages addressed. Can anyone guide me!

Comment: At first, provide your `plot.png` as an image!

Comment: Search `extract data from image`. There are many examples.