# Beautify a NDSolve Graph !

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I am doing the following:

```
xxt = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]};
eqDiff = {x1'[t] == -x1[t], x2'[t] == x2[t], x3'[t] == -15 x3[t], 
   x4'[t] == x4[t]};
inCond = {x1[0] == 0.1, x2[0] == -0.1, x3[0] == 0.2, x4[0] == 0.1};
systEq = Join[eqDiff, inCond];
sol = NDSolve[systEq, xxt, {t, 0, 2}]
Plot[xxt /. sol, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

**How can I add different Colors to the different Solutions, together with a label ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate (without the label question) of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/187

Comment: `ListLinePlot@sol[[1, All, 2, 0]]` or `ListLinePlot[sol[[1, All, 2, 0]], PlotLegends -> xxt]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Evaluate[xxt /. sol], {t, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Perfect Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

For more option for `Plot` you should visit [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

```
 Plot[Evaluate[xxt /. sol], {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {t, Xs}, ImageSize -> 700, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"x1[t]", "x2[t]", "x3[t]", "x4[t]"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Frame, LegendMarkerSize -> {{55, 10}}], {0.15, 
    0.15}]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

To improve the visibility of the frame then just add `FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]` to the above `Plot` command.
But if you are like me and always not satisfied with the plots generated by `Mathematica`, `Maple` and `Matlab`, I use [Tecplot](http://www.tecplot.com/).

To be able to produce plots in `Tecplot`, first you need to generate data from the plot you already had in `Mathematica`. This can be done like this,

```
data = Plot[Evaluate[xxt /. sol], {t, 0, 2}];
points = Cases[Normal@data, 
   Line[pts_, ___] :> Flatten[pts, Depth[pts] - 3], Infinity];
ifuncts = 
  Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2][t] & /@
    points;
data = Table[Prepend[ifuncts, t], {t, 0, 2, .1}];
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[Array["X", Length[points]], t]}]
```

I got this data extraction idea from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file).

Once the data table is generated, now then save the data to a file with any extension `.txt` or `.xls` or `.dat`.

```
Export["C:/tcdata/myfile.txt", data, "Table"]
```

Now open `Tecplot` go to file menu and click on `LoadDataFiles(s)` and then upload your file named in this case `myfile`. From here on everything is straight forward. If you new to `Tecplot`, on net you can find tutorials.

To my liking, I reproduced this plot using `Tecplot`,

[image]