# How to solve a first order coupled system of ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations

**How can I solve this coupled differential equation?**

```
ClearAll[x, y, g, w1, w2]
n = 1;b = 1;c = 1;
w1 = -(1/3) - 2 Sqrt[g[x]]/3;
w2 = -(b*b)*(1 + y[x])^n/(g[x])^(n - 1)*(1 - g[x] + y[x]);
g'[x] == -3*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + y[x]*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1);
y'[x] == -3*y[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + 
   y[x]*(1 + y[x])*(1 + 3*w1);
```

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Comment: with the initial conditions g[0] == 0.72, y[0] == 0.01

Comment: you should make that comment about initial conditions a part of your question. You should be able to edit your question by clicking on the edit link right below it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NDSolve` to solve your system of odes numerically,

```
n = 1; b = 1; c = 1;
w1 = -(1/3) - 2 Sqrt[g[x]]/3;
w2 = -(b*b)*(1 + y[x])^n/(g[x])^(n - 1)*(1 - g[x] + y[x]);
Eq1 = g'[x] == -3*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + 
       y[x]*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1)
Eq2 = y'[x] == -3*y[x]*(1 - g[x] + y[x])*(w1 - w2) + 
       y[x]*(1 + y[x])*(1 + 3*w1)
sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, g[0] == 0.72, y[0] == 0.01}, {g, y}, {x, -3, 
   3}]
Plot[Evaluate[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol], {x, -3, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

To plot `g[x]` vs `y[x]`

```
ParametricPlot[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MaxRecursion -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"g", "y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: can ı plot g(x) values versus y(x) values?

Comment: @merve Sure. `ParametricPlot[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MaxRecursion -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"g", "y"}]`

Comment: thank you, Plot[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Green}}]   ı am doing this but two of them again blue not red and green, where is the wrong?

Comment: @merve `Plot[Evaluate[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol], {x, -3, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]`

Comment: thank you so much. Last question :(. how can ı put names above the lines, such as g(x), and y(x).

Comment: @merve `PlotLegends -> {"g", "y"}`.

Comment: how can I get the datas to text or dat files? I want to plot the graphs in the another graphic programs by taking from the dates from mathematica. How can ı get?

Comment: @merve  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @merve http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file

Comment: ok I have tried p = Evaluate[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol]    Export["test.dat", p, "Table"]
FilePrint["test.dat"]
Import["test.txt", "Table"]  but say interpolating function not gives the datas

Comment: @merve http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134066/beautify-a-ndsolve-graph/134071#134071

Comment: @merve `data = Plot[Evaluate[{g[x], y[x]} /. sol], {x, -3, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick]``points = Cases[Normal@data, 
   Line[pts_, ___] :> Flatten[pts, Depth[pts] - 3], Infinity];
ifuncts = 
  Interpolation[#, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2][x] & /@
    points;
data = Table[Prepend[ifuncts, x], {x, -3, 10, .1}];
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[Array["X", Length[points]], x]}]``Export["C:/tcdata/myfile.txt", data, "Table"]`

Comment: when I want to plot w1 versus x and w2 versus x, on the positive side, y(x) is equal 0 and g(x) is equal 0,8 (example) why w2  goes to zero, is something wrong? When we put the values to w2 numerically, it does not go to zero it goes to negative values                                                           Plot[Evaluate[{w1, w2} /. sol], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

Comment: when I click at meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/ there is not any answer?