# Making Plots for Publication

Tags: plotting, publishing

I know that there is the specific package of Mark A. Caprio **SciDraw** ([[1]](http://scidraw.nd.edu/),[[2]](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8958/),[[3]](http://scidraw.nd.edu/beta/SciDrawGuide.pdf)).

But using Mathematica's own capabilities (version 10 and newer) what 
are the most common settings in order to produce publication-quality plots
(for the sake of simplicity let assume just 2d plots)?

E.g. setting figure size, fixing crowded graphs (particularly if it has multiple panels), saving graphs for modification in other art software, typesetting labels with LaTeX, ticks manipulation, CMYK color, exporting raster images etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have published four books and over a hundred articles that use *Mathematica* figures, exported as .eps and included into $\LaTeX$, with great success.  Use `ImageSize` that gives the desired published size and keep with the appropriate FontSize.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to make your question more specific. What exactly are you struggling with? Have you searched around? Are you aware of MaTeX?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Dr Stork, thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Kuba. I don't have something particular in my mind. Searching and reading about how to do publication quality plots with matplotlib module (python) it came to my minde to make a "googling" for mathematica related stuff. I have used for several years Matematica, I have some publications that I use plots and figures exported from it but I thought it was a good idea to see what settings more experienced users use.

Comment: It really varies case by case, depending on the journal you're publishing to, your personal standards/reqs, etc... The tools are almost always there, but it's hard to arbitrarily say which tools you will ALWAYS need

Comment: For my publications, I use Tecplot, which can be manipulated as you like. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134066/beautify-a-ndsolve-graph

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal  Thanks for mentioning Tecplot!