# How to extract data from BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[...]

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to extract data from a plot, more exactly `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[...]`. Following [Plot, extract data to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file), I use the following codes to make it:

```
(* Preparation *)
ball = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Region[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]];

(* I want to extract the data of ball within Polygon[] *)
Cases[ball, Polygon[data_] :> data, Infinity]
(* ==> {} *)
```

I wonder why my codes do not work, and how to extract data encapsulated in `Polygon[]`.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your knowledge and warm heart.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is *not* a plot, even though it looks like one.  It is a `BoundaryMeshRegion` expression.  Take a look at the InputForm of this, as well as Plot's output (which is a Graphics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of data you can extract from your boundary discretized region, for example :

```
ball = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Region[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]];

MeshPrimitives[ball,0] //Take[#,3]&
MeshPrimitives[ball,1] //Take[#,3]&
MeshPrimitives[ball,2] //Take[#,3]&
```

> {Point[{-0.607062, 0., 0.794654}], Point[{0.894427, 0., 0.447214}],
>   Point[{0., 0., 1.}]}
>
> {Line[{{0.276393, -0.850651, 0.447214}, {0.204995, -0.829094, 
>       0.520174}}],   Line[{{0.204995, -0.829094, 0.520174}, {0.185096, -0.890336, 
>       0.415981}}],   Line[{{0.185096, -0.890336, 0.415981}, {0.276393, -0.850651, 
>       0.447214}}]}
>
> {Polygon[{{0.276393, -0.850651, 0.447214}, {0.204995, -0.829094, 
>       0.520174}, {0.185096, -0.890336, 0.415981}}],   Polygon[{{0.185096, -0.890336, 0.415981}, {0.204995, -0.829094, 
>       0.520174}, {0.108274, -0.865931, 0.488303}}],   Polygon[{{0.185096, -0.890336, 0.415981}, {0.108274, -0.865931, 
>       0.488303}, {0.0871575, -0.92155, 0.378351}}]}

```
MeshCoordinates[ball] //Take[#,3]&
MeshCells[ball, 0] //Take[#,3]&
MeshCells[ball, 1] //Take[#,3]&
MeshCells[ball, 2] //Take[#,3]&
```

> {{-0.607062, 0., 0.794654}, {0.894427, 0., 0.447214}, {0., 0., 1.}}
>
> {Point[1], Point[2], Point[3]}
>
> {Line[{7, 38}], Line[{38, 37}], Line[{37, 7}]}
>
> {Polygon[{7, 38, 37}], Polygon[{37, 38, 483}], Polygon[{37, 483, 36}]}

```
MeshCellCount[ball, 0] 
MeshCellCount[ball, 1] 
MeshCellCount[ball, 2]
```

> 1082
>
> 3240
>
> 2160

```
MeshCellIndex[ball, 0] //Take[#,3]&
MeshCellIndex[ball,1] //Take[#,3]&
MeshCellIndex[ball,2] //Take[#,3]&
```

> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}
>
> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}

```
PropertyValue[{ball,0},MeshCellMeasure]//Take[#,3]&
PropertyValue[{ball,1},MeshCellMeasure]//Take[#,3]&
PropertyValue[{ball,2},MeshCellMeasure]//Take[#,3]&
```

> {1., 1., 1.}
>
> {0.104334, 0.122485, 0.104334}
>
> {0.00517309, 0.00546982, 0.00557218}

0,1,2 in the Mesh... expressions correspond to the dimensions of the elements you are interested in. There aren't any dimension 3 elements in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @J. M. advice. It's the very answer of my question.

```
(* extract the indexes of points, which construct the cells of mesh *)
indexOfCells = Cases[MeshCells[reg, 2], Polygon[coord_] :> coord]
(* {{56795, 56753, 56794}, ... {56793, 56752, 56751}} *)
```

With these data, I can carry out reverse engineering of msome organic texture for the mechanism of robots.