# underlying data for `QuantilePlot[]`

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, implementation-details

What is the best way to produce the actual pairs of points shown by `QuantilePlot`? Would anyone have an implementation? (I am interested in the simplest possible version: `QuantilePlot[l1, l2]`, where `l1, l2` are lists of numbers.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921651/get-points-of-listplot-in-mathematica

Comment: @VsevolodA. Yes, I am aware that `foo[[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1]]` works, but that is not the real question, since I have no idea what parameters mathematica uses (number of points, etc). I can guess, but this is not very satisfying.

Comment: Read your question again: "What is the best way to produce the actual pairs of points shown by QuantilePlot".

Comment: @Vsevolod, that's still not the best way, then; gwr's answer gives a direct method to produce the points from scratch, without the processing overhead of `QuantilePlot[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reverse-Engineering Mathematica's Q-Q-Plots**

You can also use `Quantile` directly which gives more control about what is happening and precision maybe:

Inspecting points produced by Bob Hanlon's approach and playing around with other sample sizes reveals that Mathematica appears to use the range specified by $\frac{k-0.3}{n+0.4}$ with $k = 1, \ldots, n$ to produce quantiles. Other possibilities are given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) (cf. source no. 10 for the option given here).

Thus:

```
SeedRandom[0];

data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 100];
data2 = RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[4, 2, 3], 200];

pts = With[
    {
        n = Min @@ Length /@ { data1, data2 }        
    },
    Curry[Quantile][ Table[(k - 0.3)/(n + 0.4), {k, n}] ] /@ {data2, data1} // Transpose
    (* or Map[ Quantile[#, Table[ ... ]]&] @ {data2,data1} // Transpose *)
];

ListPlot[ pts, Axes-> False, Frame -> True ]
```

[image: QuantilePlot]

We can compare with the `QuantilePlot` points using Bob Hanlon's approach:

```
pts2 = Cases[plot, Point[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];
pts2 - pts
```

> {{0.,0.}, ... , {0.,0.}}

This comparison also holds for samples sizes 200, 300 that I tested so far.

Thanks, Sjoerd C. de Vries, for pointing out the more general range-regime for Q-Q-Plots.

Comment: Nice use of the new 11.3 function `Curry` . The `Range` call, though, is only correct because data 1 happens to be 100 points long. It doesn't generalize to differently sized data sets.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. To add: the positioning method is due to [Bernard and Bos-Levenbach](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9574.1953.tb00821.x) ([English version](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/8241)). Spelunking confirms that this method is used internally by the helper function ``System`QuantilePlotDump`plottingPosition[]``.

Comment: In the case where one is comparing against a distribution instead of another dataset, `EstimatedDistribution[]` is used on the data (`NormalDistribution[]` is the default distribution to compare against), and then this is used in the computation of the second set of quantiles.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0];

data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 100];
data2 = RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[4, 2, 3], 200];

plt = QuantilePlot[data1, data2]
```

[image]

Use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to extract the points

```
pts = Cases[plt, Point[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]];

Dimensions[pts]

{100, 2}
```

In this case there are 100 points.

```
ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]