# Follow-up to "Plot, extract data to file"

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, export

This is literally a follow-up to part of Mr.Wizard's answer to: [Plot, extract data to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file/19860#19860)

Specifically in reference to

> ```
> multidat = Cases[First @ gr, Line[data_] :> data, -4];
> ```
>
> We could then export each part to a separate file like this:
>
> ```
> Export["file" <> IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #, "Table"] & ~MapIndexed~ multidat
> ```
>
> > ```
> > {"file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"}
> > ```

First, may I please get confirmation that I'm correctly reading the `~`s in the middle line as the infix version of

```
MapIndexed[Export["file" <> IntegerString[#2] <> ".txt", #, "Table"]&, multidat]
```

?

Second, is there a simple way to export `multidat` into a single file with the lines as pairs of columns? I.e., suppose `multidat` is

```
{{{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}},
 {{p1,p2},{q1,q2},{r1,r2},{s1,s2}},
 {{x1,x2},{y1,y2},{z1,z2}}}
```

How would you turn that into

```
{{a1,a2,p1,p2,x1,x2},
 {b1,b2,q1,q2,y1,y2},
 {c1,c2,r1,r2,z1,z2}},
 {,,s1,s2,,}}
```

?

Admittedly, I'm not sure how Mma would handle that last row. The data I have in mind is destined for a spreadsheet-like presentation where cells can be empty. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Join[##, 2] & @@ PadRight[multidat, Automatic, ""]
```

> ```
>  {{a1, a2, p1, p2, x1, x2}, {b1, b2, q1, q2, y1, y2}, {c1, c2, r1, r2, z1, z2}, 
>  {"", "", s1, s2, "", ""}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
MapAt[ArrayPad[#, 2, ""] &, Join[##, 2] & @@ multidat, {-1}]
```

> ```
>  {{a1, a2, p1, p2, x1, x2}, {b1, b2, q1, q2, y1, y2}, {c1, c2, r1, r2, z1, z2},
>   {"", "", s1, s2, "", ""}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are right about `Infix` as a very short experiment can verify. I will not comment on this further.

```
x ~ f ~ y === f[x, y]
```

Regarding the reshaping of your data, let me walk you through a possible solution.

```
l = {
  {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}},
  {{p1, p2}, {q1, q2}, {r1, r2}, {s1, s2}},
  {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2}}
}
```

Firstly, you probably will want to pad the list, such that the array is rectangular. I suggest here the padding `{"", ""}`. However, other paddings might be more suitable for your problem.

```
lPadded = PadRight[#, Max[Length[#] & /@ l], {{"", ""}}] & /@ l;
```

Then you can use `Flatten` to transpose everything to the form you want.

```
lReshaped = Flatten[lPadded, {{2}, {1, 3}}];
```

Finally, you can export the resulting list.

```
Export["mydata.csv", lReshaped]
```