# Plot of an even/odd function

Tags: plotting

I have an even function $f(x)$ that I wish to plot on the interval $x \in [-1,1]$. The evaluation of $f(x)$ at a given point takes a bit of time to compute, so I would want to evaluate $f(x)$ only on the interval $x \in [0,1]$ and plot the rest by making use of the evenness of the function. For example, if I do:

```
myf[x_] := (Pause[0.01]; x^2)
Show[Plot[myf[x], {x, 0, 1}], Plot[myf[x], {x, -1, 0}]],
```

the second plot is actually a waste.

I could manually make an array of $f(x_i)$ at different points $x_i \in [0,1]$, set $f(-x_i) = f(x_i)$ and then use `ListPlot`, but I feel that there should be a quicker way to do this. Ideally, something of the sort of using `Plot[myf[x], {x, 0, 1}]`, copy it, make a mirror image of it, stick the two plots together and show the result?

Comment: things like ImageReflect will not work well, due to the axis getting in the way. Better to work with the data itself directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could manually make an array of f(xi) at different points

You do not need to. Mathematica's `Plot` does it for you and it is better at sampling at the right places. (adaptive sampling).

How about getting the data points from one half of the plot, and just add minus to each x coordinate?

something like

```
myf[x_] := x^2
(*read the data from one half only *)
data = Catenate@Cases[Plot[myf[x], {x, 0, 1}], Line[data_] :> data, Infinity];

(*flip the x coordinates*)
data2 = Map[{-First@#, Last@#} &, data];

(*plot both*)
Show[ListLinePlot[data], ListLinePlot[data2], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see it is the same points used, but one half is flipped

```
Show[ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red], 
 ListLinePlot[data2, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Blue], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For an odd

```
data2=Map[{-First@#,-Last@#}&,data];
Show[ListLinePlot[data],ListLinePlot[data2],PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! How do you modify the first part for a 2D function $f(x,y)$?

Answer (score 2):

To complete Nasser's answer, the below shows how to extend the method for a 3D plot, which is inspired by an answer [to a different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file). Specifically, if $f(x,y)$ is an even function of $x$, then

```
(* plot f(x,y) for positive x only *)
myplot = Plot3D[x^2 Sin[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}];
(* read the data *)
data = FirstCase[myplot, GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> p, {}, -4];
(* flip x coordinate *)
data2 = Map[{-#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &, data];
(* plot both data together *)
Show[ListPlot3D[data], ListPlot3D[data2]]
```

Comment: This is doing too much work. You extract points out of the `GraphicsComplex[]`, only to feed them again into another plotting function that would regenerate a `GraphicsComplex[]`.

Answer (score 2):

When plotting 3D surfaces with symmetries, it is sometimes convenient to use `GeometricTransformation[]` with an appropriate choice of `ScalingTransform[]`. Using the OP's example of a bivariate function with odd and even symmetries:

```
p1 = Plot3D[x^2 Sin[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, π/2}];
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[First[p1], 
           Table[ScalingTransform[s],
                 {s, {{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}}}]], 
           Axes -> Automatic, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]
```

[image: a function with odd and even symmetries]

---

The OP's original parabola example can be treated similarly:

```
para = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}];
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[First[para],
         Table[{DiagonalMatrix[s], {0, 0}}, {s, {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}}]], 
         Axes -> Automatic]
```