# How do I get rid of a "jump" in my plot?

Tags: plotting

How can I prevent plotting functions from "connecting" *inside* a plot points that should "wrap around" *outside* the plot?

For example, how do I eliminate the horizontal lines running across the following `ParametricPlot`?

[image]

In this figure, the paths that reach the right hand end of the graph at 24 should continue at 0 (these are hours, so 24=0) without passing backwards across the figure.

---

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  {AstronomicalData[
    "Mars", {"RightAscension", 
     DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]] , $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], d},
  {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ParametricPlot[
  {AstronomicalData[
    "Mercury", {"RightAscension", 
     DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]] , $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], d},
  {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ParametricPlot[
  {AstronomicalData[
    "Jupiter", {"RightAscension", 
     DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]] , $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], d},
  {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Green]
 ]
```

---

FWIW, the (almost) final result, with help from SE:
[image]

Comment: Note, this code is absurdly slow, but that's [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11715/37).

Comment: Can't investigate at the moment (I suspect this is a matter of inverse trig branch cuts, though; see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782)), but: you can replace `{$GeoLocation[[1]] , $GeoLocation[[2]]}` with `Take[$GeoLocation, 2]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Good point. The code is adapted from cases where the latitude and longitude may be independently replaced, which is why that part is verbose.

Comment: Related: [(8576)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8576/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically the `Exclusions` option should be able to handle this but I couldn't find the right arguments.  Therefore I recommend a method similar to Simon's, but I would instead `Split` the lines where there are any large discontinuities in *x* :

```
(* Simon's code *)
plot = Show[MapThread[ParametricPlot[
 {AstronomicalData[#1, {"RightAscension", DatePlus[Date[], d], $GeoLocation}], d},
 {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> #2] &, 
 {{"Mars", "Mercury", "Jupiter"}, {Blue, Red, Green}}]];


plot /. Line[x_] :> Line@Split[x, Norm[# - #2] < 10 &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That certainly looks tidier than my [CW answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11754/37). But I'm a bit foggy on what's going on with `Line` and `:>`. Is there a reason to prefer that approach over simply including the `Split` in the plot, as in the CW answer?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the answer. My approach only works because I've "switched" to `ListPlot`, while this one works for any plot since it's operating on the `Line` primitive. (And yes, I tired `Exclusions` but could not get it to work.)

Comment: @rax I missed the CW answer. (I had this half written, walked away, and then finished it and posted.)  The `ListPlot` method is entirely reasonable, but I assumed that you specifically wanted to use `ParametricPlot`.  This method should work with any functions that have sudden "jumps" in them.

Comment: As long as there's no performance hit, this is better. Could you add a bit of explanation about what the substitution is doing for those of us who are not as sophisticated as we pretended to be. I'm always a bit puzzled about `:>`, and am not clear about how `Line` and `Norm` are working here.

Comment: @rax If you are not familiar with transformation rules you will need to [start here.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitionsOverview.html)  Specifically here the output of `ParametricPlot` is a `Graphics` object constructed of primitives such as `Line` and Options such as `PlotRange`.  My transformation rule (applied with `/.`) is `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) so that the right-hand-side does not evaluate until `x` is substituted in.  `Norm` is just a short-hand to check the distance between points; `EuclideanDistance` would work too, perhaps better.

Comment: I used to use this precise strategy of `Split[]`-ting `Line[]` objects produced by plotting functions, for removing "long" or "steep" lines in plots, before the `Exclusions` option came along. I don't know about the advantages of rewriting the splitting test in terms of `EuclideanDistance[]`, but `Norm[# - #2] < 10 &` is the same as `EuclideanDistance[#, #2] < 10 &`.

Comment: Ah, `Split`, much neater! I completely forgot about the existence of `Split`, even whilst thinking "I need to SPLIT this line into two"...

Comment: @J.M. since you are a user from early versions I'm sure you have *many* such methods that have been replaced with built-in functionality over time.  I'd be interested in seeing more of them myself, and perhaps others would too.  I often use `Norm` but `EuclideanDistance` appears to be faster.  I guess that's a habit *I* picked up before the latter was introduced and I haven't kicked it because `Norm` is shorter.

Comment: I've [updated the CW answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11754/37) to deal with a problem that arises when applying this solution to `ListPlot`. Feel free to incorporate here.

Answer (score 4):

A simple hack for this specific problem is to split each `Line` primitive into two at the first occurrence of a small *x* value:

```
plot = Show[MapThread[ParametricPlot[
 {AstronomicalData[#1, {"RightAscension", DatePlus[Date[], d], $GeoLocation}], d},
 {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> #2] &, 
 {{"Mars", "Mercury", "Jupiter"}, {Blue, Red, Green}}]];

plot /. Line[{pts1__, {x_ /; x < 1, _}, pts2__}] :> {Line[{pts1}], Line[{pts2}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might be more simplistic than you were looking for but you could always just break it up into several sections and `show` them together

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{AstronomicalData[
"Mars", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], 
d}, {d, 155, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];

p2 = ParametricPlot[{AstronomicalData[
"Mars", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], 
d}, {d, 0, 154}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
PlotRange -> All];

p3 = ParametricPlot[{AstronomicalData[
"Mercury", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], 
d}, {d, 0, 186}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Red];

p4 = ParametricPlot[{AstronomicalData[
"Mercury", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], 
d}, {d, 187, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Red];

p5 = ParametricPlot[{AstronomicalData[
"Jupiter", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], 
d}, {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, PlotStyle -> Green];

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]
```

[image]

Then you've changed the problem to writing a piece of code which detects the discontinuities and changes the indices in the plots accordingly.  I don't have a chance to do that at the moment but something which measures the distance between successive x-co-ords which stops once the difference is more than a certain threshold you set would get the job done. Mightn't be efficient or tidy but you could generate your plots in an automatic way at least.

Comment: detecting the discontinuities could be done with something like this: `mf[d_?NumericQ]:=AstronomicalData["Mars",{"RightAscension",DatePlus[Date[],d],{$GeoLocation[[1]],$GeoLocation[[2]]}}];
NMinimize[mf[d], {d, 150, 160}]`

Comment: Or even `FindMinimum[Abs@mf[d], {d, 155}]`, which is faster, but less robust and more dependent on well chosen initial conditions.

Comment: This won't help unless in includes a way to *locate* the spots that need to be excluded. For example, I'd like to put this into a `Manipulate` were I can change things like the date range dynamically.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I suggested a way to do this! It might not be the most convenient and robust method though...

Answer (score 3):

Using `ListLinePlot` with `Mesh`, `MeshFunctions`, `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading` options. The idea is to change the color of portions to be excluded to `White`.

First, the data:

```
 {dataMars, dataMercury, dataJupiter} = 
   Table[{AstronomicalData[#, {"RightAscension", DatePlus[Date[], d], 
      $GeoLocation[[;; 2]]}], d}, {d, 0, 365}] & /@ {"Mars", "Mercury", "Jupiter"};
```

Next, a function to pick the jumps in the first column of the data that exceed a threshold:

```
ClearAll[pickJumpsF];
pickJumpsF = Function[{data, threshold},
   With[{maxdif = Max@Abs@Differences[First /@ data],
         range = Abs[(Max@# - Min@#) &@(First /@ data)]},
   If[maxdif <= threshold range, {},
      First@Pick[Most@data[[All, 2]], Abs@Differences[First /@ data], maxdif]]]];
```

where a `jump` is defined as a point where the difference between two consecutive elements is greater than `threshold` times the range of the list.

Applying `pickJumpsF` with a threshold parameter `.8` to the three data sets:

```
meshpoints = Sort@Flatten@{#, # + 1} &[pickJumpsF[#, .8] & /@ 
   {dataMars, dataMercury, dataJupiter} /. {} ->  Sequence[]]
(* {154, 155, 186, 187} *)
```

Now, we can plot all three data sets in a single `ListLinePlot`:

```
ListLinePlot[{dataMars, dataMercury, dataJupiter}, 
 Mesh -> {meshpoints},
 MeshStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 MeshShading -> {Automatic, None},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Green]},
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `Split` in a `ListPlot` to introduce breaks into the data at the offending points:

```
Show[     
 ListPlot[
  Split[
   {astroData["RightAscension", "Mars", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365],
   (Abs[#2[[1]] - #1[[1]]] < 20) &
   ], PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, Joined -> True],     
 ListPlot[
  Split[
   {astroData["RightAscension", "Mercury", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365],
   (Abs[#2[[1]] - #1[[1]]] < 20) &
   ], PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, Joined -> True],     
 ListPlot[
  Split[
   {astroData["RightAscension", "Jupiter", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365],
   (Abs[#2[[1]] - #1[[1]]] < 20) &
   ], PlotStyle -> Green, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, Joined -> True],     
 PlotRange -> {{0, 24}, {0, 365}}]
```

(Using a function, `astroData`, [defined elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11753/37) to speed things up a bit.)

[image]

---

*Update*: While `Split` alone works for certain kinds of plots, it will not work for `ListPlot`, for which splitting will introduce a gap between the points where the lists are split, and the edges of the plot. This is not pronounced for steep lines, but is dramatic for shallow ones:

```
ListPlot[
 Split[
  {astroData["RightAscension", "Moon", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365], 
  (Abs[#2[[1]] - #1[[1]]] < 20) &], 
 PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, Joined -> True,
PlotRange -> {{0, 24}, {0, 365}}]
```

[image]

One way to overcome this is to "pad" the introduced gaps with "duplicates" of the points across the gap, shifted outside the edge of the plot. This can be done for arbitrary lists of data with something like

```
wrapDataList[data_, xmin_, xmax_, xgap_ ] :=
 Split[ 
  ReplaceRepeated[data, 
   {h___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, t___} 
   /; (Abs[(x2 - x1)] > xgap && x2 >= xmin && x1 <= xmax) ->
     {h, {x1, y1}, {x2 + (xmax - xmin), y2}, {x1 - (xmax - xmin), y1}, {x2, y2}, t}],
  (#2[[2]] > #1[[2]]) & ]
```

which gives:

```
ListPlot[
 wrapDataList[
  {astroData["RightAscension", "Moon", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365],
  0, 24, 20],
 PlotStyle -> Black, Joined -> True,
PlotRange -> {{0, 24}, {0, 365}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since all of the answers (notably John's [incomplete one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11717/37)) helped arrive at this, I'm making this CW. If someone wants to use this to improve their answer, I'll consider accepting that. Alternatively, please improve (or just vote up) this one so it can be taken as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how your `data` of each of your `ParametricPlot` looks like, but try to adapt the following:

```
Split[data, #1[[2]] != #2[[2]] &]
```

Comment: "I don't how your data of each of your `ParametricPlot` looks like..." - OP gave the code for producing the discontinuous plots. He wants the discontinuous plots to be made continuous, by stitching the two pieces together.

Comment: @J.M.  
I'm not familiar with `AstronomicalData` but maybe it is possible to produce the data via `Table` (i.e. wrapping `AstronomicalData` with `Table`) and then to use `ListLinePlot` with `InterpolationOrder->3`.

Comment: That won't cure the problem OP has; the function itself has a (spurious) discontinuity that needs to be remedied. See [this similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to first use `Clip` to keep all differences between consecutive data points within a given range, then reconstruct the list using `Accumulate`:

```
dataMars =  Table[{d, AstronomicalData["Mars", {"RightAscension", 
 DatePlus[Date[], 
  d], {$GeoLocation[[1]], $GeoLocation[[2]]}}]}, {d, 0, 365}]

dataFixed[data_, minDiff_, maxDiff_] := With[{diff = Differences[data[[All, 2]]]}, 
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Accumulate[
    Join[{data[[1, 2]]}, Clip[diff, {minDiff, maxDiff}]]]}]]

dataMars2 = dataFixed[dataMars, 0.0394, 0.0559];
dataMercury2 = dataFixed[dataMercury, -0.08668, 0.1493437];
dataJupiter2 = dataFixed[dataJupiter, -0.00969, 0.01664];

ListLinePlot[{dataMars2, dataMercury2, dataJupiter2}]
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't what the figure should look like. See my clarification and the figure in [fizzics answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11721/37).