# Why is AstronomicalData so slow?

Tags: curated-data, performance-tuning, astronomy

I'm having trouble getting some pretty simple functions using `AstronomicalData` to perform at anywhere near the speed I need them to.

For example, I have many places where I need to compute something like

```
ParametricPlot[
 {AstronomicalData[
   "Mercury", {"RightAscension", 
    DatePlus[Date[], d], {$GeoLocation[[1]] , $GeoLocation[[2]]}}], d},
 {d, 0, 365}, AspectRatio -> 1/1.6]
```

but find that it takes far to long for even this simple fragment to run. I want to put several such fragments (e.g. one for each of several astronomical objects) into a [single figure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11714/37), and even to dynamically change the parameters for the figure (such as location and date) inside a `Manipulate`, which would be prohibitively slow given the times I'm seeing with even the simple fragment above.

Why is `AstronomicalData` so slow? Is there something I can do to speed it up so I can use it as I hope to?

Comment: Looks like you're downloading data from the internet for every point... perhaps [preloading the data to your disk](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3310) might help. I don't have *Mathematica* to test it right now

Comment: Just to make sure: have you done what @rm -rf has suggested (i.e., executing `AstronomicalData[All, "Preload"]` before doing anything else)?

Comment: @J.M.: Yes, but the plot still takes the same time. Perhaps that only loads data for the current day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once can see by using `Trace` that an apparently simple call is far more complex than you might imagine.  Why it is designed this way, and if it needs to be, is an entirely different matter.

Be prepared to forcefully terminate *Mathematica* (or at least `Quit[]` the kernel) and then run:

```
AstronomicalData["Mercury",
  {"RightAscension", {2012, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, $GeoLocation}
] // TracePrint
```

A lot more going on behind the scenes than a simple database look-up, eh?

Comment: Yes, that "entirely different matter" keeps coming up with *Mathematica*. One wonders whether there is any thought given to use cases or architecture at all.

Comment: @rax Oh, I'm sure thought has been given.  I wish that they'd be more transparent about the limitations of the design, trade-offs made, and places they simple haven't optimized well (Calendar package, PlotLegends, etc.).  I didn't even start trying to look through the massive Trace output above, but I'd guess from the length of it that *Mathematica* is *calculating* the information requested (from more fundamental data) rather than simple doing a database access.  That may be a reasonable trade-off for certain applications, yet cause trouble for yours.

Comment: (Sigh.) Well, in any case, [caching what I need](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11753/37) is a serviceable, if inelegant, solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way to overcome this issue is simply to define functions to store the data, so that it `AstronomicalData` is only needed once for each value, using something like

```
astroData[datum_, object_, dayoffset_, location_] :=
 (astroData[datum, object, dayoffset, location] =
   AstronomicalData[object, {datum, DatePlus[Date[], dayoffset], location}])
```

Then the data can either be preloaded, with something like

```
astroData["RightAscension", "Mercury", #, $GeoLocation] & /@ Range[0, 365];
```

and will in any case accumulate through use so that execution eventually becomes quite speedy.

---

The example above becomes

```
ListPlot[{astroData["RightAscension", "Mercury", #, $GeoLocation], #} & /@ Range[0, 365],
    AspectRatio -> 1/1.6, Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf is right:

```
AstronomicalData["Mercury"]
```

then execute your command.  It takes about 25 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Sorry, no, see above: this needs to run inside a `Manipulate`, so 25 seconds is *way* too slow. And in any case, running `AstronomicalData` beforehand makes no difference in performance (at least not for me).

Comment: @rax: Worse comes to worst, you might have to roll your very own ephemeris... :|

Comment: Have you actually *tried* this? This doesn't do anything at all, it just returns an empty list { }. But it does it fast! :-)

Comment: The first time I run this - at the start of every Mathematica session - I get the "Initializing indices..." messages for about 10 seconds. Then the expression returns the string "Mercury". Subsequent calls for the expression in that session are immediate. But the parametric plot still takes 15 seconds...

Comment: @J. M. Mathematica's `AstronomicalData` uses a precessing reference frame, and I want ICRF 2000, so rolling my own ephermis is exactly what I'm doing: downloading the SPICE kernels (http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/kernel.html), importing them into Mathematica, and then saving them as .mx dump files for faster loading. Seems to help quite a bit.

Comment: @barry, a look at all the formulae involved quickly shows how nontrivial that project is. Best of luck! Do you plan to release code when you're done?

Comment: It's messy, but https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/ASTRO has enough code to compute planetary positions (but you have to download the SPICE kernel files separately). I used this to compute Regulus/Jupiter/Venus conjunctions for http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/has-the-conjunction-between-venus-jupiter-and-regulus-only-occurred-twice-in-2 and to find a 15-year-old bug (now fixed) on the calsky.com site. If there's interest, I can release the .mx dump files, but these are ~300M for every 1000 years of data (and I'm only looking at the visible planets).