# How to remove vertical lines in ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

I am ploting electronic band structure in Mathematica using `ListLinePlot`. Like this

[image]

However I don't want those vertical Lines indicated by red circle.

I want to delete those vertical lines and get this feel

[image]

An idea maybe to post-process the plot and keep styles intact. But I got lost in the complicated FullForm of Plot.

A simple example to start is for example `ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: `ListLinePlot[
 Split[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, First[#] != First[#2] &], 
 Frame -> True]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11714/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-jump-in-my-plot -- The post-processing methods of some answers should work, and kglr's solution shows how to do it with `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Hi, @kglr. Thanks for your answer. The problem is that your method breaks one line into two line, and viewed as two colors. What if I want to visualize multiple lines

Comment: @matheorem, as you suggested post-processing is  a way to keep the styles intact:  `ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, Frame -> True] /. 
 Line[x_] :> (Line /@ Split[x, First[#] != First[#2] &])`

Comment: @kglr Works like a gem! Thank you so much!

Comment: Are the jumps always between points with equal, integer first coordinates?

Comment: Hi, @MichaelE2. In my case the jump occurs in two points with same x, not necessarily integer. Do you have more general solutions?

Comment: Often the x-coordinates are close together and not necessarily equal, but it depends on how the data are generated. One could use Mr.Wizard's answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11755/4999), adjusting the `Split` criterion to the scale of the data as necessary (e.g. change `< 10` to `< 0.1`, or perhaps using the slope & bounding box of the data for the criterion).  @kglr used the same approach as Mr.Wizard (post-processing with `Split`), but my thought was that what criterion works depends on the data and what should count as a gap.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Umm, how about making thick gridlines/simple vertical lines at the high symmetric points? This is what the second curve is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[postProcess]
postProcess = # /. Line -> Function[{x}, Line /@ Split[x, First[#] != First[#2] &]] &;
```

Example:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3,  2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}}}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Green, Thick]}, 
   ImageSize -> 250];


Row[{llp, postProces@llp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]