# Help remove annoying vertical lines in a piecewise plot

Tags: plotting

I use the following codes to define and plot three piecewise functions.

```
list1 = Join[
   Table[{(j - 1)/2^1, (j - 1)/2^1 <= E^x < j/2^1}, {j, 1, 
     1*2^1}], {{1, E^x >= 1}}];
list2 = Join[
   Table[{(j - 1)/2^2, (j - 1)/2^2 <= E^x < j/2^2}, {j, 1, 
     2*2^2}], {{2, E^x >= 2}}];
list3 = Join[
   Table[{(j - 1)/2^3, (j - 1)/2^3 <= E^x < j/2^3}, {j, 1, 
     3*2^3}], {{3, E^x >= 3}}];
p1 = Piecewise[list1];
p2 = Piecewise[list2];
p3 = Piecewise[list3];

Plot[p1, {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Plot[p2, {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Plot[p3, {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

p1 and p2 just come out fine, while p3 is messy, with end points of each horizontal lines connected by vertical lines.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [(8576)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8576/121), [(10501)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10501/121), [(11714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11714/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using @Rojo's answer to my question [**here**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8576/193) you don't need to know a priori where the exclusions are:

```
plot = Plot[p3, {x, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 1000];

pp = With[{multiplier = {AspectRatio, PlotRange} /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[plot, {AspectRatio, PlotRange}] /. {ar_, pl_} :> 
                             ar Divide @@ Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ pl}, 
  (plot //. 
   Line[{a___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, b___}] /; 
     Abs[(y1 - y2)/(x1 - x2)] > 10/multiplier :> {Line[{a, {x1, y1}}],
      Line[{{x2, y2}, b}]})
 ];

Show[pp, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Do you feel this question can be marked as a duplicate of [(10501)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10501/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not exactly that one.Here we are talking specifically about `Piecewise[ ]` which may allow some messing with the `Piecewise[ ]` specificities if someone else care to do it.

Comment: Okay, good point.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that to find the discontinuities, `Plot` internally calls

```
PiecewiseExpand[p3, Method -> {"OrderlessConditions" -> True}]
```

but with a time constraint of `0.2` seconds.  (See [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) for an explanation of the option.) Because of the somewhat complicated conditions on `x` -- ok, inequalities in terms of `E^x` may not seem that complicated to a good high school student, but *Mathematica* apparently thinks so -- it takes much, much more time than that.  The time constraint `0.2` seems to be hard-coded, so we cannot easily approach the problem from that angle.  A better way is to simplify the function first using `Reduce` to get the inequalities in terms of `x`:

```
PiecewiseExpand[p3, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> (Reduce[#, x, Reals] &)}]
```

Then we get

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  PiecewiseExpand[p3, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> (Reduce[#, x, Reals] &)}],
 {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, Exclusions -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Evaluating the `PiecewiseExpand` **before** passing it to `Plot`, either using another variable to store the result or using `Evaluate` as above, is necessary.  Otherwise the internal call to `PiecewiseExpand` will be made on the input `PiecewiseExpand[p3,...]`, which will take longer than `0.2` seconds.  In that case, the discontinuity processing fails and you get the annoying vertical lines.

---

**Update:**

The point of the option `"OrderlessConditions" -> True` is the reduce the conditions to non-overlapping intervals.  The irony is that `p3` already satisfies that criterion.  So we can mimic the internal processing of the discontinuities, which is faster than simplifying them with reduce:

```
excl = With[{p = p3[[1, All, 2]]},
   Thread[
    (LogicalExpand /@ p /.
       {f_ <= g_ :> f - g, f_ < g_ :> f - g, f_ >= g_ :> g - f, f_ > g_ :> g - f, 
        And -> Max}) == 0
    ]
   ];
Plot[p3, {x, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Exclusions -> excl]
```

The plot looks the same.

Comment: I wonder if the Villegas-Gayley trick is usable here to thwart the arbitrary time constraint…

Comment: @J. M. I thought about that, but setting the time to 600 seconds still failed.

Comment: @J. M.  Basically, the time complexity of `PiecewiseExpand[p3, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> (Reduce[#, x, Reals] &)}]` in this case seems to be roughly proportional to $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of pieces in `p3`.

Comment: "Exponential in the number of pieces" is indeed slow… indeed, it does seem best to preprocess your discontinuous function before feeding it to `Plot[]`.

Comment: @J. M. Oops, I meant the option `"OrderlessConditions" -> True`.  Oh, bother....

Answer (score 3):

```
 Plot[p3, {x, -3, 3}, 
      Exclusions -> Table[Exp[x] == j/2^3, {j, 1, 3*2^3}], 
       PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

or if you don't know where the jumps are:

```
 ListPlot[GatherBy[Table[{x, p3}, {x, -3, 3, .01}], #[[2]] &],
     Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

this could be extended with a tolerance as, `Gather[ .. , Abs[#1[[2]]-#2[[2]] ]< eps & ]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression @@@ list3], {x, -3, 3}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Blue, BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

In 10.2 there is `ListStepPlot`.

```
ListStepPlot[Table[{t, p3 /. x :> t}, {t, -3, 3, 0.001}], Joined -> False]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.